# Does Array create a new Object of the added Class?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to add different classes (example: Dog, Cat, Mouse) from the same instance to an Array (example: Array animals).

Example code:

```
Array<Animal> animals = new Array<>();
Cat cat = new Cat();
Dog dog = new Dog();

animals.add(cat);
animals.add(dog);
```

Does: `animals = new Array<>()` create new Object of Dog, Cat.. etc.?

because I don't whant two objects of the same class, just a Array that refers to
these classes

Comment: No, it creates an Array (whatever that is, is that a class of yours?)

Comment: The array can only have objects of one type. If `Dog`, `Cat`, etc. are subclasses of animal, then you can have an array of `Animal` objects.

Comment: Yes its my own class.

Comment: Since `Array` is your own class, how can we hope to tell you what it does or doesn't do?

Comment: If `Array` is your own class, and you don't show us the source code, then you are the only one that can answer your own question... we don't know what the constructor of your class `Array` does, so we can't tell if it creates `Dog` or `Cat` objects.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that `Array<T>` is a simple array that functions like a standard collection type.

No, it simply allocates a block of memory that you can point to your objects once you create them.

```
Array<Animal> animals = new Array<>();
```

Will find a block of memory for you. When you do:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
```

You will create a pointer to the object `cat`. When you do:

```
animals.add(cat);
```

You will put the pointer in the first position in the block of memory that the array has allocated.

Answer (score 0):

What is an "`Array<Animal>`"? In java, it would be either an `Animal[]` or something like `List<Animal>`. In both cases, no Animal objects would be created, just something to store them in - later.

Comment: Is the List interface compatible with libGDX?